# foundation-icon-fonts and react and webpack

Tags: reactjs, zurb-foundation

I would like to use foundation icons with my react.js web page. I have installed foundation-icon-fonts with npm, but what would be the further steps to include the icons into my page?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to link the Foundation Icon Font CSS file to your page and then you can use it normally - just keep in mind that you have to exchange all `class` attributes to `classNames` attributes when using React:

```
<i className="fi-check"></i>
```

You can also wrap the icon into stateless React component by something like this:

```
const FoundationIcon = (props) => (
  <i className={`fi-${props.iconName}`}></i>
);

FoundationIcon.propTypes = {
  iconName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

And then use it:

```
const Button = () => (
  <button type="button" className="button">
    <FoundationIcon iconName="check" />
    <span>I get it</span>
  </button>
);
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/69485/)